# Spring Auth + JWT login response 200 but body and headers missing

Tags: java, spring, jwt, fetch

I am having a bit of a tough time with Spring Security. Basically I have `/auth/signup` and `/auth/login` for account creation and obtaining jwt token, respectively.

Both work perfectly locally via Insomnia/POSTman *but* when making the request to `/auth/login` from the React.js front-end with `fetch()` it either returns a CORS preflight request error OR gives an "opaque" or "cors"  200 OK response with *no body*. The latter is of no use as I need the token. The thing that's annoying is it works on Insomnia.

Here's what the response looks like when triggered via `fetch()` from javascript locally. There's no body and no headers. Where as with Insomnia or POSTman, there are headers and a body.

[image]

I've tried quite a few different things over the last few weeks including:

- Adding custom `addCorsMappings()` call in an impl' of `WebMvcConfigurer`
- CORS filter `@Component` which overrides `doFiler()` and has a bunch of `setHeader()` calls.
- CORS config configuration class with `corsConfigurer()` as a `@Bean`
- Another `Bean` inside custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` returning `CorsConfigurationSource`

The truth is, I don't know which of these is the most up to date, correct one to use. I've read so many things (mostly stack overflow articles and tutorials) that have not helped. It feels so wrong just pasting in snippets without having a full understanding of if it will work or how. If anyone can describe the correct way of configuring CORS to work with a `fetch()` call from React and not just POSTman/Insomia - I'd be very grateful.

I'll include as much source as I can, but will exclude things like user classes here. It's my understanding they are fairly standard, for the most part.

`WebMvcConfig.java`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 360;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry){
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With", "requestId", "Correlation-Id")
                .exposedHeaders("Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With", "requestId", "Correlation-Id")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
    }
}
```

`SimpleCORSFilter.java`:

```java
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {


    public SimpleCORSFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");


        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, requestId, Correlation-Id, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

`CorsConfig.java`:

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now here's the `SecurityConfig.java` class making use of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Notice the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` and `CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()` methods.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.
                userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/polls/**", "/users/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With", "requestId", "Correlation-Id"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }



}
```

I have these two routes in the `/auth` Controller:

```java
   @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(path = "/login", produces = { "application/json" }, consumes = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword())
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(path = "/signup", produces = { "application/json" }, consumes = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest){

        if (userClient.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new ApiResponse(false, "Username already being used!"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        AppUser user = new AppUser(signUpRequest.getUsername(), signUpRequest.getPassword(), "ADMIN");
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        AppUser result = userClient.save(user);


        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/users/{useranme}").buildAndExpand(result.getUsername()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(new ApiResponse(true, "Success: User registered"));

    }
```

Finally the javascript fetch call:

```java
fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/auth/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'accept':'*/*' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ "usernameOrEmail": username, "password": password })
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

Years late, but the problem was that  I wasn't `.json()` on my request on the client side. Facepalm

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the component scan annotator.
The following code work for me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MainAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'am using CrosFilter with the React front-end. After apply CrosFilter I didn't face any issue. Try to use the CrosFilter. Find the below sample.

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Comment: Hey @darshakat can you tell me which class this Bean should be in?

Comment: @ColinRiddell, Since I'm using Spring Boot, I placed this in SpringBootApplication class (main class). You can place this any 'Configuration' class. Just put this to your CorsConfig class (replace WebMvcConfigurer Bean) and try.

Comment: I tried this and it's still giving me either a 200 cors response with no body, or an opaque response. I really don't know what I am doing wrong here.